# Maven : How to avoid version appended to a war file in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2, build

I am using Maven as the build file , this is my below settings for the war file  name  to be generated

I am using Maven version 2.2.1

```
     <artifactId>TataWeb</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
```

So its actually generating a war file with this name  TataWeb-1.0

But i want the war file name to be only TataWeb .

Please let me know how can i avoid the version appeneded to the war file name ??

Thank you .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <finalName>TataWeb</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: I have 6 pom.xml files , one is parent one , where exactly i need to add this ??

Comment: @user1253847: in the `pom.xml` responsible for generating WAR file, i.e. the one with `<packaging>war</packaging>`.

Comment: Ya i did that , but that did not work , still its generating with Tataweb-1.0.war , i have added the pom.xml file , please see .

Comment: @user1253847: are you sure you are building your application with `tata` profile? Because the `finalName` is defined only there.

Comment: The finalName will only prevent adding the information in the target folder but will not prevent the information added during deployment.

Answer (score 9):

You should use your artifactid, rather than hard-coding the file name.

```
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: Much better like this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

well, its not the Maven Way. Maven does have a version attribute.. use it.

Comment: Even though it is not the maven way, there are some cases when someone has to do this.

Answer (score -2):

You can avoid the version appeneded to the war file name by doing a "clean compile package" instead of "clean install".

Comment: Because, this will not install it to the local maven repo. So, file name changing angle, it is similar to build/finalName solution given above IMO.